# Porting Java: C++ --> Class types

Tags: java, c++, hash, dictionary, porting

I'm considering porting the  java library [Artemis](http://gamadu.com/artemis/). An entity system framework. I havn't started yet. Instead I have been analyzing the internal works of how the java code is put together. I know there is half worked up [CPP port](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1390/entry-2254064-c-port-of-artemis-entity-component-system-framework-in-progress/).

I've looked at both codes and noticed that the java code puts certain things more elegantly.
And mainly the following:

```
package com.artemis;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ComponentTypeManager {
    private static HashMap<Class<? extends Component>, ComponentType> componentTypes = new HashMap<Class<? extends Component>, ComponentType>();

    public static final ComponentType getTypeFor(Class<? extends Component> c){
        ComponentType type = componentTypes.get(c);

        if(type == null){
            type = new ComponentType();
            componentTypes.put(c, type);
        }

        return type;
    }

    public static long getBit(Class<? extends Component> c){
        return getTypeFor(c).getBit();
    }

    public static int getId(Class<? extends Component> c){
        return getTypeFor(c).getId();
    }
}
```

And the componentType "object"

```
package com.artemis;

public class ComponentType {
    private static long nextBit = 1;
    private static int nextId = 0;

    private long bit;
    private int id;

    public ComponentType() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        bit = nextBit;
        nextBit = nextBit << 1;
        id = nextId++;
    }

    public long getBit() {
        return bit;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Basically what the componentTypeManager does is map a componentType to a class type.
Which makes it dynamic when adding new components.

The C++ port solution is as follows:

```
#ifndef __COMPONENT_TYPE_H__
#define __COMPONENT_TYPE_H__

namespace SGF
{
    enum ComponentType 
    {
        CT_TRANSFORM = 0,
        CT_HEALTH,
        CT_RENDERABLE,
        CT_RIGID_BODY,
        CT_JOINT,

        CT_LAST
    };

    // Component type bits. Used by the entity systems to determine if an entity is compatible.
    const unsigned int CT_TRANSFORM_BIT  = 1 << CT_TRANSFORM;
    const unsigned int CT_HEALTH_BIT     = 1 << CT_HEALTH;
    const unsigned int CT_RENDERABLE_BIT = 1 << CT_RENDERABLE;
    const unsigned int CT_RIGID_BODY_BIT = 1 << CT_RIGID_BODY;
    const unsigned int CT_JOINT_BIT      = 1 << CT_JOINT;
};

#endif
```

Here the ComponentManager is completely left out. Instead an enum is used.
My problem with this is the fact you have to add new component types to the enumerator and the constants as "type" identifiers. The java framework allows you to pass a component class type to identify it's id.

My question is, how would I go about to get a similar effect of passing a type to map it's id like the Java code without hard coding enumerator types for every new component?
I know C++ doesn't support class types as arguments. So this is rather mind boggling to me.

Comment: May `std::type_info` serve as a replacement for _class type arguments_?

Comment: @K-ballo wouldn't that mean I have to create my object first to read the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are not planning to instantiate components given their component type, and assuming that `Component` has one or more `virtual` function, using [*RTTI*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) should be sufficient for your purposes. You can use [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/) in place of `HashMap`, and replace the `Class<C>` with `type_info`.

One thing I'm not certain about is how `ComponentType` would know what exact bits to return: the code instantiates `ComponentType` with no parameters when one is not found in the map, yet it's assumed that different instances would return different patterns of set and unset bits. I assume this is because your hash map is pre-populated for known component types, though.

Comment: ComponentType calls init in the constructor. The init function sets the next available id type internally. The "bit" is meant to work in conjuncture with a "System" object (which is the logic for each component where the component itself is just data for the entity) which collects entities depending on their bit id and either removes them or adds them to be processed.

The id and bit are statically 1 upped on every new ComponentType instance.

Comment: +1. For the bit/id hack in the ComponentType, I'd suggest using a vector of bool (this is the *one* case where its peculiar implementation would be helpful), or an object wrapping a vector of bool. It will go well beyond the limitation of Java's 64-bit long.

Comment: @paercebal Could you allaborate a bit more on the vector bool. What aspect of the code are you talking about specifically?

Comment: I take it back for the `vector<bool>`. The Java implementation is limited to 64 different component types, as the `long` type has in Java, at most, 64-bit, but this value is a primitive, "on the stack", and thus, cheap to copy/etc.. A std::bitset could well set a different (and quite higher) limit on that, at zero cost (if its implementation is done correctly). The std::vector<bool> would offer a dynamic bitset, whose size can grow at runtime, unlike the `long` or `std::bitset` types, but it would probably need allocation on the heap (depending on implementations), which make a copy not cheap.

Comment: @Sidar : The "bit" part of the Java implementation is a long, which can, at most, contain 64 bits. I don't know what this framework is used for (looking at the links, I see it's for games), so perhaps 64 components at most is Ok. But, for a "framework", without this prior "it's for games" knowledge, this Java code seems quite vulnerable to silent breakage if you go beyond the 64-component-max limit. This is why I suggested the vector<bool> to simulate a bitset that could grow beyond the 64-bit limit.

Comment: @paercebal I was actually aware of the limitation. But I don't see how I would perform bit operations on them. In other classes operations like ~ ^ & and | are used. While I get the concept you are giving with the boolean vector I'm kinda lost on how to process them fast.

Comment: @Sidar : A C++ compiler is quite adept at optimizing away most (if not all) abstractions away, so the code that seems heavy to you because of indirections/function calls could well resolve itself in raw, simple operations after compilation. Did you actually compare performance between a std::bitset an simple integer? Did you actually looked at the generated assembler code after optimized compilation? Did you actually measured the bottleneck of your application is in the bitwise operations? Note that bitwise operations are slower we commonly expect anyway...

Comment: @Sidar : ... All this to quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". If you have the ambition to port a framework to C++, making it "fast and safe" is better than making it "fast", and a lot better than "I'm coding it in C because I believe this will produced even faster code". Looking at the C++ Standard Library would bring you quite efficient abstrations at zero or negligible cost. Another solution, look at EA's homegrown version of the STL. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html for more info about the performance issues they had with STL.

Comment: @paercebal: I meant that I have no clue on how to perform bit operations on a vector with booleans =). But I've looked at BitSet and it provides all that( I assumed you were talking about std::vector, which confused me). It will take a couple more days to grasp the structure of the java framework. The C++ port seems to implement many things differently. Thanks for your replies though.

Comment: @Sidar : `I meant that I have no clue on how to perform bit operations on a vector with booleans =)` : Oops, sorry. I misunderstood you, then... :-)